# Need linq help: Trying to add detail to master

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I haven't done much dealing with header and detail records.  I need to create an order object
and add an IList<lineItems) to a property within the header records.  I was trying to do a
join and gave up.  I call two stored procedures, one for header and one for details.
All I want to do is populate my "IList" in the header payload.  I keep getting "a query body must end with a select" and not sure how to accomplish.  I'm certain there are better ways
using a join but if I can get this to work I'd be thrilled.

````
var orderHeaderRecords = ctx.sparGetOrderConfirmationRecords_WED(runDate).ToList();
var orderDetailRecords = ctx.sparGetOrderConfirmationRecordsDetail_WED(runDate).ToList();

var order = (from o in orderHeaderRecords
//gave up on join
//join od in orderDetailRecords on new { o.RecordType, o.OrderNumber } equals new { od.RecordType, //od.OrderNumber }
  
 select new OrderConfirmation()
 {
    BillAddr1 = o.BillToAddr1,
    BillAddr2 = o.BillToAddr2,
    IsOfficeOrder = Convert.ToBoolean(o.IsOfficeOrder),
    OrderConfirmationType = EnumHelper.GetValueFromDescription<ConfirmationType>(o.RecordType),
    LineItems = new List<LineItem>()
 }).ToList();
 
order.ForEach(or =>
                    
                    {   or.LineItems.AddRange((from line in orderDetailRecords.Where(x => 
                        x.RecordType == or.OrderConfirmationType.ToDescription() 
                        && x.OrderNumber == or.OrderNumber).Select(od =>

                        new LineItem(
                          {
                             Desc = od.Description,
                             ExtAmt = od.ExtPrice.Value,
                            ItemId = od.Item                                                  } 
                          ).Select(rec => rec).ToList()); //.ToList()));

                    });
```
The last line of code (body must end with a select or group by)  
I just need to get the detail records in the "List" on the master record.
````

Answer (score 0):

```
order.ForEach(or =>                    
{   or.LineItems.AddRange(
    orderDetailRecords
    .Where(x => x.RecordType == or.OrderConfirmationType.ToDescription() && x.OrderNumber == or.OrderNumber)
    .Select(od =>
        new LineItem(
            {
                Desc = od.Description,
                ExtAmt = od.ExtPrice.Value,
                ItemId = od.Item                                                  } 
            )).ToList());
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Jim G.  Much appreciated.  That did the trick.

Comment: @Joe Kehnast: Good to know. You can upvote my answer and mark it as the accepted answer if it helped you.